# Transient Entity Update via CrudRepository

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When updating a Record/Entity, do I have to create a detached entity first then save.

```
Entity e = entityRepository.findById(id);
// set necessary properties for update
entityRepository.save(e);
```

or a transient entity would do? Given that the id exists.

```
Entity e = new Entity();
// set necessary properties for update
entityRepository.save(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the entity which we get by find operation is in **persistent** state and not **detached** state

Both the cases would work but the only thing you need to take care is that your save statement should have proper **transaction**.